# Modificar colunas dos dados no R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Tenho uma planilha em Excel com as expectativas de inflação para os 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025 ao longo dos últimos 30 dias. Quando eu faço a importação dessa planilha, as datas estão sendo consideradas como uma coluna, e na verdade as variáveis deveriam ser somente os anos.
Eu precisaria ter um data frame com 5 variáveis e 19 observações e não 6 variáveis com 19 observações.
Como eu faço pra o R entender que as datas não são uma variável?

Essa é a cara dos meus dados :

[image: dados]

Para importar, eu usei esse código:

```
expec_anual_ipca <- read_excel("expec_anual_ipca.xls")
```

Comment: Seria bom se pudesse compartilhar uma amostra dos seus dados com ``dput(head(df))`, em que df é seu data.frame.

Comment: Você poderia tanto usar um comando como `select` para remover esta coluna ou até indicar isso no comando de importação que estiver utilizando como um argumento

Comment: Olá Vinícius, obrigado pelo comentário! Mas eu não quero remover, quero apenas que a coluna das datas não seja lida como uma variável....

Answer (score 2):

Se instalar o pacote `cellranger` pode especificar as colunas a ler.

```
colTypes <- rep("numeric", 5)
cols <- cellranger::cell_cols(2:6)
expec_anual_ipca <- read_excel("expec_anual_ipca.xls", 
                               col_types = colTypes, 
                               range = cols)
```

Ou, mais simples,

```
expec_anual_ipca <- read_excel("expec_anual_ipca.xls", 
                               col_types = rep("numeric", 5), 
                               range = cellranger::cell_cols(2:6))
```

Também pode especificar por nomes das colunas. Neste caso assumo que a 2ª coluna é a coluna `"B"`, a 3ª é a `"C"`, etc, até à coluna `"F"`.

```
expec_anual_ipca <- read_excel("expec_anual_ipca.xls", 
                               col_types = rep("numeric", 5), 
                               range = cellranger::cell_cols("B:F"))
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Rui!!! Vou tentar aqui, instalando esse pacote que eu não conhecia. Valeu mesmo!